# How to deploy to a single selected target in an Azure Devops Deployment Group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

**Is there a way how to select a single target and perform a deployment against it in an Azure devops Deployment Group Release Task?**

E.g: In a web servers deployment group a deployment of, say a certificate failed against a single machine. I 'd like to now deploy this certificate only on that target. How can I do as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue, you can specify the tag of the target machine in the **Required tags** field.

[image]

The tags you assign allow you to limit deployment to specific servers when the deployment group is used in a Deployment group job. Tags are each limited to 256 characters, but there is no limit to the number of tags you can use. For details,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops).

[image]

Or you can disable other targets in the Deployment pools of organization setting. This can disable deployment to this target.

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: New targets added to the deployment group don't get deployed/released to automatically. Can we set that up somehow?

Comment: You can refer to this earlier [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/296594/automatically-deploy-to-new-targets-in-a-deploymen.html)

Comment: I know this is 4 years later, but is the Tags column still present for you? I only see Online and Last Deployment on the Targets tab.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to the case, you can also use conditioning option in the release task.

Step1 : Create Pipeline variable which contain the server name you wanna deploy.
[image]

Step2 : Add a custom condition on the task.[image]

```
and(succeeded(), contains(variables['IncludeServers'],variables['Agent.MachineName']))
```

Step 3: Add as many server you wanna add in the pipeline variable
Result:
[image]